# How to store the data on every instance of do-while loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, store, do-while

I am currently studying Java and I need to add the values of every instance in my do-while loop. Is there some way to store the values so it won't be overwritten every loop?

```
import java.util.Scanner;   

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    char userChar;

    do {

        System.out.println("Apples are $10");
        System.out.println("How many do you want?");
        int itemQty = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Do you wish to buy more? (y/n)");
        userChar = input.next()charAt(0);

    } while (userChar == 'y');

    // all values entered by the user needs to be added 
    System.out.println("The total is: $" + (itemQty*10)); 

}
```

}

Comment: Move `int itemQty` outside of the loop, and then write `itemQty += input.nextInt()` that way you're creating a sum of apples which you can print at the end

Comment: It's been bugging me for hours!! It works now, huge thanks man!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable for the totalSum outside of the loop and then everytime the user enters a number, add itemQty to it.

```
int totalSum = 0;
do {
    ...
    int itemQty = input.nextInt();
    totalSum += itemQty;
    ...
} while (...);
// Here totalSum is the sum of all user inputs
```

Answer (score -1):

you can update your program like this below -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    char userChar;
    int itemQty = 0;

    do {

        System.out.println("Apples are $10");
        System.out.println("How many do you want?");

        itemQty += input.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Do you wish to buy more? (y/n)");
        userChar = input.next().charAt(0);

    } while (userChar == 'y');

    // all values entered by the user needs to be added
    System.out.println("The total is: $" + (itemQty*10));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    char userChar;

        int itemQty=0;
        int totalQty=0;
    do {

        System.out.println("Apples are $10");
        System.out.println("How many do you want?");

        itemQty = input.nextInt();
        totalQty+=itemQty;
        System.out.println("Do you wish to buy more? (y/n)");
        userChar = input.next()charAt(0);

    } while (userChar == 'y');

    // all values entered by the user needs to be added 
    System.out.println("The total is: $" + (itemQty*10)); 
}
}
```

As suggested by Lino, Keep itemQty outside the loop and initialize it to zero.

Do you also want to store the value of itemQty for every loop iteration?

If yes then use ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<int> valuesList = new ArrayList<int>();
```

and change your loop code to

```
int itemQty=0;
int totalQty=0;
do {

    System.out.println("Apples are $10");
    System.out.println("How many do you want?");
    itemQty = input.nextInt();
    valuesList.add(itemQty*10);//New line to be added
    totalQty += itemQty;
    System.out.println("Do you wish to buy more? (y/n)");
    userChar = input.next().charAt(0);

} while (userChar == 'y');
```

And then after the loop ends, display the values in each stage.

```
for (int i = 0; i < valuesList.size(); i++) {            
      System.out.println("The value of Qty in stage "+(i+1)+" is $"+valuesList.get(i));       
  }
```

And this will be your final output

Apples are $10
How many do you want?
10
Do you wish to buy more? (y/n)
y
Apples are $10

How many do you want?

5

Do you wish to buy more? (y/n)

n

The total is: $150

The value of Qty in stage 1 is $100

The value of Qty in stage 2 is $50

Comment: If it's possible, yes